# How to use ECPublicKeyImpl in Java 11

Tags: java

We are migrating to `Java 11` from `Java 8` but `ECPublicKeyImpl` doesn't seem to work. How can we use it in `Java 11` as it is a `Sun` class.

The ECPublicKeyImpl used an encoding that came from `ECUtil`. However in `Jdk11` since this class is not available the encoding seems to be different. We need to use the `EC` algorithm for encoding. Is there an alternative?

Answer (score 1):

An alternative that you can use is `java.security.*` which is compatible with `java-11`, the [KeyFactory](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/KeyFactory.html) and [PublicKey](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/PublicKey.html) classes could be helpful.

```html
...

PublicKey key = KeyFactory
  .getInstance("RSA")
  .generatePublic(new RSAPublicKeySpec(modulus, exponent))
  
...
```

Comment: Updated my question with more comments. This answer is not relevant for us.